# Logic reasoning problems books

Tags: logic, deduction, syllogism

Could you, please, recommend any books with a set of logic problems or exercises on deductive and inductive reasoning, syllogism.

Something that contains a set of questions, such as

It is known that all humans are mortal. Socrates is mortal. Is it true that Socrates is human?

Comment: Maybe Laszlo Csirmaz & Zalán Gyenis, [Mathematical Logic Exercises and Solutions (Springer, 2022)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Mathematical_Logic/rzZzzgEACAAJ)